# Running chmod command as root with "."

Tags: linux

```
Line#1 pwd
Line#2 /Users/jigarnaik/Documents/test
Line#3 sh-3.2# chown -R jigarnaik .
```

What will be the effect of line no 3 ? 
Will it change owner of the entire device in linux OS OR 
the current folder  and it's sub-folders OR 
all the folders and files in the path given ?

I ran the command as root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will change the owner of the current directory and all subdirectories.

Comment: okay, i thought when we check the disk space . represent entire device. so when i change the owner using . it will change the owner of entire device.

Comment: *It will change the owner of the current directory and all subdirectories.* Nope. It will change the owner of the current directory, all subdirectories, and *all files therein*. Please double-check your answer if you insist on answering non-programming questions.

Comment: Of course the contents of the directories (the files) will be affected to. Most importantly it will not affect all files and directories in the system.